# How do I get the name of the Scenario step currently executing?

Tags: java, cucumber

I'm logging the currently executing Scenario in a hook like so:

```java
@Before(order=2)
public void logScenarioStarting(Scenario scenario) {
  logger.debug("Starting scenario {}.", scenario.getName();
}
```

But, how do I get the name of the Step? I mean, the `Given`, `When`, `Then` lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to implement the ConcurrentEventListener interface and setup the handlers for the event you are looking for, in your case the TestStepStarted event

```
@Override
public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
    publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepStarted.class, this::handleTestStepStarted);
    publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepFinished.class, this::handleTestStepFinished);
    
}
```

Then implement the method `handTestStepStarted`

```
private void handleTestStepStarted(TestStepStarted testStepStartedEvent) {
    if(testStepStartedEvent.getTestStep() instanceof PickleStepTestStep) {
        PickleStepTestStep pickleStepTestStep = (PickleStepTestStep)testStepStartedEvent.getTestStep();
        //do what you want with it
    } 
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. Now I have enough terms to search for.